# Phpmyadmin показывает нагрузку на процессор 100%,но консоль показывает около 15%

Tags: phpmyadmin, консоль, процессор

Phpmyadmin показывает нагрузку на процессор 100%, но консоль показывает около 15%.
Тогда **откуда же берет такие цифры pma**?
Причем раньше такого не было-pma показывал верные значения....а теперь нет, хотя ничего не менялось - конфиги не редактировались и ничего не обновлялось.
phpmyadmin version 4.0.5, libmysql - 5.0.95, PHP version 5.5.17

Comment: Линух. Буду копать в сторону proc/stat...

Comment: Видимо - из-за системных обновлений теперь немного не так, как раньше пишется информация в файле stat.

Answer (score 1):

Какая у вас OS?

Посмотрите [в исходнике](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/libraries/sysinfo.lib.php), метод `loadavg()` для своей ОС. Для Windows берётся информация из WMI, в Linux читается '/proc/stat'.